# How to avoid access db compaction?

Tags: microsoft-access

My access db pulls data through odbc every few mins and deletes data in local tables and writes new data. After a while db size exceeds 2gb and it has to be compacted. How can I avoid this compaction step? Linking with odbc is not an option.

Comment: This is the very core of Access design (deleted data doesn't actually removed until we use compact) and at least other DB like SQL Server (empty space is kept until we call shrink, which hurt performance). I would just use an instance of SQL Express LocalDB (10GB limit, depending on the design you might get away with no shrinking or perhaps scheduled shrinking), but since you mentioned linking with ODBC is not an option, I guess it doesn't apply to your situation.

Comment: Is this an Access application or is Access only being used as a database?  If Access is only being used as a database then what is scheduling the work at regular intervals?  Which version of Access are you using?  I wonder about automating the repair and compact...would that help or not really?

Comment: I am currently using AHK to automate compaction every hour but want to avoid it.